# Xcode not accepting 72x72px app icon?

Tags: ios, xcode, icons

im having trouble with getting my app icon for an ipad app into xcode, ive made it and exported it from photoshop as a png, usually i can just drag it from the finder straight into the app icon section in xcode but it dosnt work it just dosnt get loaded into the place holder.

Its odd becuase its a 72x72px 72dpi png with no alpha 46kb.. but the retina 144x144px 72dpi png 66kb with alpha works

any ideas what might be causing this ?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding it manually? (right click on the "no image specified" area in your screenshot and then 'select file') Is there an actual error message?

Comment: Did you try Ctrl-Click -> 'Select File' ?

Comment: I think icon size could be 57x57 px.

Comment: @tendulkar yes it is 57x57, but this is for ipad so its 72x72 ill update the question to make it clear

Comment: @luke adding it manually worked, thanks allot !

Comment: Ah excellent - shall I post as an answer?

Comment: yeah, just something to add if its also in the left hand side bar you can double check that its been added into the project, so if its in there you can drag it in from the left sidebar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment posted on request as answer:

Have you tried adding it manually? (right click on the "no image specified" area in your screenshot and then 'select file') Is there an actual error message?